# How can I swap values of variables in Visual Basic? (applies to any programming language)

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner practicing writing code. I have this homework question:

> Given two double variables, `bestValue` and `secondBestValue`, write some code that swaps their values. Declare any additional variables as necessary.

That is what I wrote:

```
Dim thirdValue as Double 
thirdValue=3.3

 Dim fourthValue as Double 
fourthValue=4.4

bestValue=thirdValue
secondBestValue=fourthValue
```

And that is what I got from the system:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have only declared two variables and using four, bestValue and secondBestValue are not declared.

Comment: Are you sure the question matches the code and the result? I can't see variables named `firstPlaceWinner` and `secondPlaceWinner` anywhere in ether the code or the result, altought they are explicitly mentioned in the question?

Comment: My bad, it wasn't that assignment. I just edited it and the question is actually: !!!Given two double variables , bestValue and secondBestValue, write some code that swaps their values. Declare any additional variables  as necessary!!! Doesn't the statement : Given two double variables! already mean that these variables have been declared? thanks

Comment: Hint: you hold something in each hand. Now swap those items (without throwing/juggling). You may use extra hands to temporarily hold an item as needed.

Comment: Declare a variable called whatever and assign `bestValue` to it. Then assign `secondBestValue` to `bestValue` then assign the new variable to `secondBestValue`. Swap done.

Comment: The IDE has nothing to do with the language. Swapping variables is the same in all almost all languages - you use a temporary variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double bestValue = 1;
double secondBestValue = 2;

double temporary = bestValue;
bestValue = secondBestValue;
secondBestValue = temporary;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the vars are int or double you can do:

```
double bestValue = 1;
double secondBestValue = 2;

bestValue = bestValue + secondBestValue;
secondBestValue = bestValue - secondBestValue;
bestValue = bestValue - secondBestValue;
```

This way you don't need the temporary var